# how to make a photo mosaic like on the mozabrick website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, image, frontend

Maybe someone knows how to make a photo mosaic like on this site https://mozabrick.ru/magic/upload . After uploading the image, the photomosaic is generated somehow. How can this be implemented on React js? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVdIE.jpg)

I searched and tried various libraries, but the result is not what it should be

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.